# Public access issue for ESXi guest host

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a ESXi server with two NICs. Recently, I configured reverse proxy based on Apache, and in order to test it, I started using both NICs for public and private connections. I created a public VM network using NIC2. I configured my guest VM (Ubuntu 12.04) with two NICs and assigned each NIC to different networks. So, my guest VM works fine, I have access to both, Internet and local network. However I cannot access it from Internet. It is not even ping-able, UNLESS I am doing an external ping. Once I am pinging a public IP, I can access (ping or http) my guest VM from internet. What have I missed in configuration? Thanks in advance.